# Use ios health kit to get swimmingStrokesCount

Tags: ios, watchkit, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I'm trying to get swimming strokes count from health kit. I'm starting workout of type swimming and then try to access swimming strokes with code:

```
        let swimmingStrokesCountQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: swimmingStrokeCountType!, predicate: nil, anchor: nil, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit), resultsHandler: { (query, sampleObjects, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) in
        self.updateStrokes(samples: sampleObjects)
    })

    swimmingStrokesCountQuery.updateHandler = {(query, samples, deleteObjects, newAnchor, error) in
        self.updateStrokes(samples: samples)
    }

    healthStore.execute(swimmingStrokesCountQuery)
```

But I don't get any samples. When I try to get steps with running workout type it works with similar code. Is it possible to get swimmingStrokeCount or watch simply does not provide it and I should implement stroke count by myself? Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution to this question?

Comment: Finding me to..........